# Cannot Send File in Response

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a code set that runs on the server, which correctly generates a zip file and stores it on the server.  I have that file location as a physical path.

Nothing I have attempted has allowed me to use the response to the client to download that file.

Attempt 1:

```
System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(zipFilePath);

//setup HTML Download of provided Zip.
//application/zip
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ContentType = "application / zip";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
"attachment; filename=\"" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(zipFilePath) + "\";");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fi.Length.ToString());

Response.TransmitFile(zipFilePath);

Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

No result.  Code executes without error but there is no download to the client.

Attempt 2:

```
//Almost the same as attempt 1, but with WriteFile instead
Response.WriteFile(zipFilePath);
```

No Result, same as Attempt 1.

Attempt 3:

```
//Note: Same Header Section as Attempts 1 and 2
System.IO.BinaryReader reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(new System.IO.FileStream(zipFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open));

int CHUNK = 1024;
List<byte> FileArray = new List<byte>();
while (reader.BaseStream.Position < reader.BaseStream.Length)
    FileArray.AddRange(reader.ReadBytes(CHUNK));

byte[] bArray = FileArray.ToArray();
reader.Close();

Response.OutputStream.Write(bArray, 0, bArray.Length);

Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

No Result, Same as previous attempts

Attempt 4:

```
//Identical to Attempt 3, but using BinaryWrite
Response.BinaryWrite(bArray);
```

No Result, Same as previous Attempts.

**The Question**

Every one of these code blocks runs with no error, But The Save File dialog NEVER appears.  I get nothing at all.  I cannot figure out for the life of me what I might be missing.

- *The File Path has been verified as correct*
- *The Code is running on the server, not on the client, I cannot use the 'WebClient.Download' method for this reason*

If anyone has any suggestions, I'm all ears.  I have no idea how to get this file to download to the client.

Comment: I don't think you have spaces in your mime type. It should be `application/zip` like you have it in your comment.

Comment: Have you tried examining the network traffic in your browser? You can use something like fiddler or even just look at the Network tab in the browser diagnostics (F12 in IE, CTRL+SHIFT+i in Firefox, etc.)

Comment: Spaces in mime / content type shouldn't be any problem (although, there's no need for spaces in the first place).

Comment: Change your download file extension to txt or pdf and try again

Comment: I can't for the life of me figure out why this is being downvoted.  No one bothered to leave any comment explaining it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an Ajax related error causing issues between UpdatePanels and POST Responses.

The issue was fixed on the page load of the page by adding the call

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(btnGenerate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code (attempt 1) and got it working fine with a test file. If the file path would be wrong, you'd get an `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` so that's probably not the issue.

A couple of ways to address this:

- Try inspecting the webpage in, for example, Chrome by right-clicking
  and choose `inspect`. Then click on `Network` tab, and refresh the
  page (where you're supposed to get the file). Check the response
  headers for that request - what is it?
- Try setting content-type to `application/octet-stream`
- Use debugger in Visual Studio and step through.